# SymfonyBundle: How to pass to a controller as a service the full bundle configuration

Tags: symfony, autowired

I've created a bundle completely separate from the main app, so I install it via Composer.

This bundle requires some sort of configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
shq_mybundle:
    node1:
        node1_1:
            ...
        node1_2:
            ...
    node2:
        node2_1:
            ...
        node2_2:
            ...
```

My bundle also has a controller `MyBundleAController` and this controller has a `––construct()` with this signature:

```
class MyBundleAController
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, array $config)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->config = $config;
    }
}
```

My bundle also loads a `services.yml` file that uses autowiring to configure controllers:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to d

    SerendipityHQ\Bundle\MyBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../Controller/*'
        public: false
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Obviously, the way `MyBundleAController` is configured throws an error, as the `$config` argument is unknown by the autowiring functionality that requires the argument be typehinted or explicitly set:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "SerendipityHQ\Bundle\MyBundle\Controller\MyBundleAController":
>   argument "$config" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or
>   be given a value explicitly.

And here we arrive to my question: the `$config` parameter is the one that someone sets in its `app/config/config.yml`, so this one:

```
# app/config/config.yml
shq_mybundle:
    node1:
        node1_1:
            ...
        node1_2:
            ...
    node2:
        node2_1:
            ...
        node2_2:
            ...
```

How can I pass `shq_mymodule` configuration to the autowired controller?

In a first attempt, I've tried to do something like this

```
    SerendipityHQ\Bundle\MyBundle\Controller\ConnectController:
        arguments:
            $config: "%shq_mybundle%"
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

To make it work I should do something like this in `MyBundleExtension`:

```
$container->setParameter('shq_mybundle', $config);
```

This way I transform it in a parameter accessible from the `services.yml` file that can use it to autowire the `MyBundleAController` controller.

**But this seems to me like an hack: is there a more elegant way to do this?**

Comment: The most elegant way would be to define shq_mybundle as a parameter to begin with.  Assuming you don't actually need it in your extension.  By the way, need to define your controller service with public: true so the controller resolver can access it.

Comment: @Cerad, no, I need it to configure some services. `shq_mybundle` cannot be a parameter because concretely is a really complex configuration for the bundle, with a lot of parameters and variable sections. It builds some connectors, and each connector has its own name and its own configuration validated by `Configuration.php`, and the names are defined by the developer when uses the bundle... It is not a simple parameter...

Comment: Then why would want to pass all that stuff to a controller?  Off topic I know.  If you are using it in your extension then setParameter is they only way I know to make it available.  You could also define this rather alarming controller service in your extension making the services.yaml stuff go away.  Or if you need to use the shq_mybundle info in multiple services then wrap it all in an object.

Comment: A more elegant way to do this would be to keep your controller doing controller things and move your logic to a proper service ;)

Comment: Yes, is off topic :) Anyway, because in the configuration there is the name of an entity class that I need to load in the controller: is the procedure to get access tokens in an OAuth flow. For this reason I need the full config...

Comment: @NicoHaase , damn, so simple and obvious! I'll go this way! Thank you!